# '/testfor' a number more than 0

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a points shop for kills. I have the objectives money and kills. When I press a button, a command block tests for my kills (hopefully) above 0, and if that is a thing, it takes gives me one money and takes one kill. But this never happens because it always "Finds" me, and now my kills are in the negative.

TLDR: How to `/testfor` a number only above zero?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this is to have it when you press the button, for something costing 3 'points', have a command block with the command `/testfor @p[score_TEST_min=3]` This will make it so the *minimum* score you can have is 3. So, if your score is smaller than 3, it can't take away points.

Remember, it can be any number, just substitute the number 3 for the number of points something costs. Lead a redstone comparator out of that command block, and to the command blocks that take the 3 points away from you, and give you the item(s). (I'm assuming you already have the commands for these, if you don't, leave a comment, and I will add them.)

Comment: But... Does it? I tried that.